# How to add flowmonitor in on-off application?

Tags: c++, ns-3

Can anyone suggest how to add flow monitor in on-off application in NS-3. Modified Example file build successfully but didn't write any *.xml file, Below is the code :

Any suggestions ? What is wrong here ? it looks like the API is correct.

```sh
  AsciiTraceHelper ascii;
  Ptr<OutputStreamWrapper> osw = ascii.CreateFileStream ( (tr_name + ".tr").c_str());
  UanPhyDual.EnableAsciiAll (osw);

  std::string tr_name ("ULSR");
  Ptr<FlowMonitor> flowmon;
  FlowMonitorHelper flowmonHelper;
  flowmon = flowmonHelper.InstallAll ();
  flowmon->CheckForLostPackets ();
  std::map<FlowId, FlowMonitor::FlowStats> stats = flowmon->GetFlowStats ();
  for (std::map<FlowId, FlowMonitor::FlowStats>::const_iterator m_numNodes = stats.begin (); m_numNodes != stats.end (); ++m_numNodes)
    {
        NS_LOG_UNCOND("Flow ID: " << m_numNodes->first << " Position of sink: " << sink.Get (0) << " Dst Addr " << sinkDev.Get (0));
        NS_LOG_UNCOND("Tx Packets = " << m_numNodes->second.txPackets);
        NS_LOG_UNCOND("Rx Packets = " << m_numNodes->second.rxPackets);
        NS_LOG_UNCOND("Throughput: " << m_numNodes->second.rxBytes * 8.0 / (m_numNodes->second.timeLastRxPacket.GetSeconds()-m_numNodes->second.timeFirstTxPacket.GetSeconds()) / 1024  << " Kbps");
    }


  Simulator::Stop (m_simTime + Seconds (0.6));

  Simulator::Run ();

  flowmon->SerializeToXmlFile ((tr_name + ".flowmon").c_str(), true, true);

  Simulator::Destroy ();

  return m_bytesTotal;
}
```

Here is the output of the command prompt:

```sh
[2772/2852] Compiling scratch/uan-rc-example.cc
[2807/2852] Linking build/scratch/uan-rc-example
Waf: Leaving directory `/home/jay/Documents/dev/workspace/ns-allinone-3.30/ns-3.30/build'
Build commands will be stored in build/compile_commands.json
'build' finished successfully (4.457s)
param=1:  Received 910000 bytes at sink
```

Thanks. Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the problem correctly, you're trying to get the print statements in the for-loop to run. FlowMonitor collects statistics of the simulation as it runs. You have placed the for-loop before the `Simulator::Run()` call, so you are trying to print the statistics of the simulation before it has run! My guess is that `flowmon->GetFlowStats()` returns an empty map, so you don't have a null pointer that would cause your program to crash: the for loop simply finds that the map is empty, and doesn't run.

The solution is simple: move the following code to after the call to `Simulator::Run()`:

```
flowmon->CheckForLostPackets ();
std::map<FlowId, FlowMonitor::FlowStats> stats = flowmon->GetFlowStats ();
for (std::map<FlowId, FlowMonitor::FlowStats>::const_iterator m_numNodes = stats.begin (); m_numNodes != stats.end (); ++m_numNodes)
{
      NS_LOG_UNCOND("Flow ID: " << m_numNodes->first << " Position of sink: " << sink.Get (0) << " Dst Addr " << sinkDev.Get (0));
      NS_LOG_UNCOND("Tx Packets = " << m_numNodes->second.txPackets);
      NS_LOG_UNCOND("Rx Packets = " << m_numNodes->second.rxPackets);
      NS_LOG_UNCOND("Throughput: " << m_numNodes->second.rxBytes * 8.0 / (m_numNodes->second.timeLastRxPacket.GetSeconds()-m_numNodes->second.timeFirstTxPacket.GetSeconds()) / 1024  << " Kbps");
}
```

You also have to move the `flowmon->checkForLostPackets()` call since that is how FlowMonitor will do a final roll call to determine which packets are missing (ie. dropped) *after* the simulation has completed running.